# UglifyJS to transform javascript code

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, uglifyjs

I am trying to use UglifyJS for the first time. Iwould like to tranform the below code using UglifyJS

```
function someFn(){
        var someVar="test";    
        if(browser=="IE7"){
        ....
        console.log("something");
        console.log("somethingelse");
        .....
        }
        else{
        ....
        console.log("nothing");
        console.log("nothingelse");

        .....

        }
}
```

to produce below output

```
function someFn(){
        var someVar="test";
        ....
        console.log("something");
        console.log("somethingelse");
        .....
}
```

What I have tried is below

```
if (node instanceof UglifyJS.AST_If){
return node.body;
}
```

but this gives below output

```
function someFn(){
                var someVar="test";
              {
                ....
                console.log("something");
                console.log("somethingelse");
                .....
               }
        }
```

Comment: apart from the extra block (2 chars), there is not really any difference between the two.

Comment: you can nootice that there is no else block, also the if condition should be removed..my whole idea is to make the code specific to IE7 if I find an if condition which matches IE7..hope I am clear..you can also see that I am getting "{" braces

Comment: there is no `if` or the corresponding `else` block in the output as shown. The only difference is a pair of braces

Comment: yes, you are right.. I am unable to remove those braces thru UglifyJS

Comment: @Jan Dvorak any solution?

Comment: My only suggestion is not to care, sorry. Why do you mind them?

Comment: @JanDvorak since I am doing a transformation to other file there will be these extra braces which I want to get rid of them..also, node.body is an object can't I get only content out of it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UglifuJS provides a method to do it as below

```
return UglifyJS.MAP.splice(node.body.body);
```

The above code will remove those extra braces.